# How to free up space in /boot when there are no extra kernals

Tags: storage, boot-partition

I need to free up space in /boot but a lot of functionality is limited on my computer because /boot is so full! I tried deleting old kernals but I don't have any. I also tried removing things with apt-get but that fails because /boot is too full to write to the disk at all.

How can I free up this partition enough so I can download a bootable usb iso so I can resize my partion?

(note, I can't download files because there isn't enough 'swap space' for firefox to complete a download)

Comment: Are you sure you are using right terms? Swap? Download? /boot? Swap is a separate partition which is not acceptable to you. It is a space which system uses to put data from RAM if it gets full. You have separate partition for /boot or you are just talking about its directory? Have a look on /var/log/ maybe you have many huge old logs

Comment: What is the output of `du -h --max-depth=1`

Comment: You don't need free space in /boot to download files.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up borrowing someone else's computer to make a bootable usb and increase the size of my root partition.